# How i can fix this error, when importing my database?

Tags: mysql, nextcloud

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_appconfig` (
`appid` VARCHAR( 32 ) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
`configkey` VARCHAR( 64 ) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
`configvalue` CLOB DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `appid` , `configkey` )
);
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLOB DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`appid`, `configkey`))' at line 1

How i can fix this error. Pls Guys. I need my NextCloud!

Comment: Change `CLOB` to `BLOB`?

Comment: Where does this come from? Did you copy paste it from somewhere?

Comment: This is my old Database from OwnCloud. I now wanna make it with NextCloud.

Comment: If you ask me (just saying) ... if you have read the error message more closely, then you _could_ have solved that problem in less than a minute, which is ... certainly faster than posting a question here on SO and waiting for an answer ...

Comment: @KarelG - Yes, I agree. The error message should be self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry @KarelG , but i am started programming before 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has no `CLOB` data type. Use `TEXT`.

[See the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the Import works perfect!:)